# Assign to the maximum value the ID column

Tags: r, max

I have the following:

```
a <- c("ID_A", "ID_B", "Count")
b <- c("1", "1015", "19389")
c <- c("1", "1019", "206")
d <- c("1", "1027", "1210")
e <- c("2", "1019", "206")
f <- c("2", "1027", "1210")
df <- data.frame(a, b, c, d, e, f)
```

I want first to pivot_wider, that is get rid off the abcdef.
Then, I want to extract the maximum value of count, create a new variable (mutate) that has the ID_B of the highest value.

Something like this, with pivot_wider to get rid of abcdef:

```
a <- c("ID_A", "ID_B", "Count", "ID_B of max value")
b <- c("1", "1015", "19389", "1015")
c <- c("1", "1019", "206", "1015")
d <- c("1", "1027", "1210", "1015")
e <- c("2", "1019", "206", "1027")
f <- c("2", "1027", "1210", "1027")
new_df <- data.frame(a, b, c, d, e, f)
```

I tried group_by, sum, mutate. It doesn't work.
Help please!
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You could attempt this in a number of ways...however, it sounded like you might be interested in a `tidyverse` approach. If so, you can use both `pivot_longer` and `pivot_wider` to evaluate the max `Count`. Based on your example, it sounds like for each `ID_A` you want the `ID_B` that has the maximum `Count` value (unclear how you want to handle ties, if that is possible...in this case will just use the first `ID_B`). After you indicate which `ID_B` has the maximum `Count`, you can do the same to revert back to your original format.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -a, names_to = "old_vars", values_transform = list(value = as.numeric)) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = a) %>%
  group_by(ID_A) %>%
  mutate(ID_B_Count_Max = ID_B[Count == max(Count)[1]]) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -old_vars) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = old_vars)
```

**Output**

```
  name               b     c     d     e     f
  <chr>          <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 ID_A               1     1     1     2     2
2 ID_B            1015  1019  1027  1019  1027
3 Count          19389   206  1210   206  1210
4 ID_B_Count_Max  1015  1015  1015  1027  1027
```

Comment: Thank you Ben, let me be more clear. Please see the answer to my question.

Comment: It works in the end !!! Thank you so much!!!

Comment: @dreamR Great! [Feel free to accept answer if appropriate.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

I have made a couple of assumptions about your data, first that you intended the numbers to be numerics, and second that the data frame should be transposed so that it has columns ID_A, ID_B, and Count.

```
a <- c("ID_A", "ID_B", "Count")
b <- c(1, 1015, 19389)
c <- c(1, 1019, 206)
d <- c(1, 1027, 1210)
e <- c(2, 1019, 206)
f <- c(2, 1027, 1210)
```

I am using the `data.table` library, so make a `data.table` with your data:

```
library(data.table)
df <- as.data.table(rbind(b,c,d,e,f))
names(df) <- a
```

Now I can make a new variable called `ID_B of max value` which corresponds to the value of `ID_B` at the value that maximises Count.

```
df[, `ID_B of max value` := .SD$ID_B[which.max(.SD$Count)] , by=ID_A]
df
   ID_A ID_B Count ID_B of max value
1:    1 1015 19389              1015
2:    1 1019   206              1015
3:    1 1027  1210              1015
4:    2 1019   206              1027
5:    2 1027  1210              1027
```

A few aspects of `data.table` to note here.  First, the `:=` operator is a special assignment operator.  `.SD` means the current subset of the data, so with `by=ID_A` it corresponds to the subset defined by each value of `ID_A`.